# How do I block packets coming on port 23 on my computer?

Tags: c, linux, networking, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I am using libpcap library. I have made one packet sniffer C program using pcap.h. Now I want to block packets coming on port 23 on my computer via `eth0` device. I tried pcap_filter function but it is not useful for blocking.
Please explain to me how to code this functionality using c program.

Comment: What's wrong with a firewall?

Comment: I am asking that does libpcap library have any function to block packet?

Comment: There is more than one port 23. You need to be specific as to the transport protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Libpcap is just used for packet capturing, i.e. making packets available for use in other programs. It does not perform any network setup, like blocking, opening ports. In this sense pcap is a purely passive monitoring tool.

I am not sure what you want to do. As far as I see it, there are two possibilities:

1. You actually want to block the packets, so that your computer will not process them in any way. You should use a firewall for that and just block this port. Any decent firewall should be able to do that fairly easy. But you should be aware, that this also means no one will be able to ssh into your system. So if you do that on a remote system, you have effectively locked out yourself.
2. You still want other programs (sshd) to listen on port 23 but all this traffic is annoying you in your application. Libpcap has a filtering function for that, that is quite powerful. With this function you can pass small scripts to libpcap and have it only report packets that fit. Look up filtering in the pcap documentation for more information. This will however not "block the traffic" just stop pcap from capturing it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually using pcap you are not able to build firewall. This is because packets seen inside your sniffer (built using pcap) are just copy of packets which (with or without sniffer) are consumed by network stack.
In other words: using filters in pcap will cause that you will not see copies of original packets (as far as I know pcap compiles filters and add those to kernel so that on kernel level copy will not be done); anyway original packet will go to network stack anyway.

The solution of your problem most probably could be done by **netfilter**. You can register in NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING hook and there decide to drop or allow given traffic.